# When to close connection in multiple method calls

Tags: java, jdbc, connection

I have the following scenario:

```
MethodA() calls MethodB()
MethodB() calls MethodC()
```

All methods have to execute some query to DB. So, to do this I create a connection object and pass it along the chain of methods to reuse the connection object.

Assumption here is that connection pooling ***is not*** being employed.

Now my question is, 
 should only a single connection be opened and reused and be closed at the starting point (in the above example, the connection will be opened and closed in MethodA) ?
 or 
 should I create a separate connection for each method?

Reusing the connection seems better, but then I will have to keep the connection open till the control comes back to MethodA().

I have read that reusing the connection is better as they are expensive to create. But then I have also read that its better to close the connection as soon as possible, i.e., once you are done with the query call.

Which approach is better and why?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are only querying the DB and not updating or inserting.  If that is the case then you avoid many of the transactional semantics in such a nested procedure call.

If that is true, then simply connect once, do all your querying and close the connection.  While usage of a connection pool is somewhat orthogonal to your question - use one if you can.  They greatly simplify your code because you can have the pool automatically test the connection before it gives one to you.  It will auto-create a new connection if the connection was lost (let's say because the DB was bounced).

Finally, you want to minimize the number of times you create a DB Connection BECAUSE it is expensive.  However, this is often non-trivial.  Databases themselves only support a maximum number of connections.  If there are many clients, then you would need to take this into consideration.   If you have the trivial case - one database and your program is the only one making connections, then open the connection and leave it open for the duration of the program.  This would require you to validate it, so using a DB Pool, size of 1, avoids that.